# Convert ECIES ECP CryptoPP to JAVA

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce, elliptic-curve, crypto++

I have a 202 byte key and that is used to decrypt a binary file.

```
StringSource keyStr( key, Z3_KEY_LENGTH, true );
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor ellipticalEnc( keyStr );
unsigned char *tmpBuffer( new unsigned char[ src.Size() ] );
DecodingResult dr = ellipticalEnc.Decrypt( rng, src.Data(), src.Size(), tmpBuffer );
```

I tried to use jsafejce for this:

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", "JsafeJCE");
PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
Cipher eciesDecrypter = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES/SHA1/HMACSHA1", "JsafeJCE");
```

and

```
Cipher eciesDecrypter = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithXOR/SHA1/HMACSHA1", "JsafeJCE");
```

But with the first I get a block error, must be divided by 16, and with the second I get a mac check error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't really know what you are trying to do in your code. I'll try and answer some of the questions.

---

> Convert ECIES ECP CryptoPP to JAVA

To get the point out of Crypto++, its about as hard as:

```
// Assuming your key was DER Encoded
byte key[Z3_KEY_LENGTH] = ...;

ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor decryptor;
decryptor.BERDecodePublicKey(ArraySource(key, sizeof(key)).Ref(), false, sizeof(key));

const ECPPoint& point = decryptor.GetPublicElement();
const Integer& x = point.x;
const Integer& y = point.y;
```

If your key was not DER Encoded, refer to [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) from the Crypto++ wiki. You also have the wiki page on [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme).

Java 7 provides and [ECPoint class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPoint.html), and it takes an X and Y coordinate.

---

```
> ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor ellipticalEnc( keyStr );
> unsigned char *tmpBuffer( new unsigned char[ src.Size() ] );
> DecodingResult dr = ellipticalEnc.Decrypt( rng, src.Data(), src.Size(), tmpBuffer );
```

This does not look quite right, but you have not showed enough code.

```
size_t maxLength = decryptor.MaxPlaintextLength( src.Size() );
unsigned char *tmpBuffer = new unsigned char[ maxLength ];

DecodingResult dr = ellipticalEnc.Decrypt( rng, src.Data(), src.Size(), tmpBuffer );
if( !result.isValidCoding )
    throw runtime_error("failed to decrypt cipher text");

unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[ result.messageLength ];
std::cpy(tmpBuffer, buffer, result.messageLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some empty bytes to the end of your key so that it is 208 bytes long? That might fix your block size error.